# Collections for hierarchies

Tags: c#, .net, collections

In the app I am writing, I am trying to find a way to store hierarchies effectively. Here is an [example](http://www.battlestarvfx.com/images/bsg_breakouttutorial/BSG_TUT_CompTest_Fusion_GUI.jpg).

At the bottom, you can see the nodes to be stored. Should I use multi dimensional lists? That doesn't seem very optimal, right? I was thinking holding references like so:

```
node.Parent
node.Children { collection }
```

Anyone has experience with this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly basic implementation of a tree, yes. If choose to make your collection for the children an IList or IEnumable or ArrayList, etc is up to you.

I would strongly suggest you build a generic implementation instead of one typed to your domain model, however that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, in your second paragraph, you mean writing a generic CustomCollection<T>?

Comment: No, more Like Treenode<T> which contains TreeNode<T> Parent and IEnumerable<Treenode<T>> Children

Comment: Note that it only applies, as Lucero mentions in a post below, if all objects are of the same type or abstraction thereof.

Comment: Thanks, so like Node : BaseNode, Node Parent, IEnumerable<Node> Children ? If I do that, would the Parent/Children cast the actual class down?

Comment: Have two generic type parameters, one for branches, one for leaves.

Comment: That's very good advice. I tend to use trees where leaves can be branches, but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: If you use generics, you will have to have a non-generic base class (or an interface) which you also use as constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.  You have the right idea.  If you need a two-directional hierarchy, I wouldn't use a multi-dimensional list... I would add a node to the tree and each node contains a parent and a collection of children.

You are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

If not all items are of the same type, I may use an abstract base class for a linked list and children collections in such a situation.

Comment: Thanks, so like Node : BaseNode, Node Parent, IEnumerable<Node> Children ? If I do that, would the Parent/Children cast the actual class down?

Comment: We,, I guess the children can be of different types. However, using generics, you could in fact have a strongly typed parent if necessary. But usually you just use the base class in this pattern.